# Laptop with smaller spacebar

Tags: laptop, keyboards

I use the AltGr key quite a lot and it hurts sometimes when I use it frequently. I think the spacebar is way to big. I understand that it should be easy to reach but you would have no problem using a spacebar that was 1/2 - 3/4 the normal size. I'm looking for a laptop where the spacebar is smaller so that the modifier keys are easier to access. I would also be interested in other keyboard layouts that makes modifier keys easier to use.

Comment: Toshiba?  Otherwise, this is pretty niche and not standard.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths What do you mean? What's "pretty niche and need standard"? Did you try to send a link?

Comment: To clarify: keyboards come in a pretty standard size on laptops.  You've not shown any research of your own on this problem.  A smaller than normal space bar is going to be a pretty niche product.  If it exists.  The closest thing I checked for resulted in Toshibas looking to have a smaller space bar.  Have you looked?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments its niche product. Even I've been looking for laptop with small spacebar

The best I could find is japanese laptops (with JIS layout) which have small spacebar (language can be changed to English and keyboard Type to ANSI)

you could have a look at JIS keyboard @ https://www.apple.com/jp/macbook-air/

Use Karabiner-Elements https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements on macOS to map extra keys according to your convenience